# WooCommerce REST API - filter what meta_data is sent in orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

[image]**Problem**

We are using Zapier to fetch orders from WooCommerce, through the REST Api. We encountered an error that Zapier can't recieve some orders because of the data sent by WooCommerce is to large (more than 7MB).

This is caused by the plugin Fancy Product Designer, which sends a PNG image as a base64 string in the **line_items meta_data** (see example of this in the image  above).

Can't find any documentation or hooks on how to filter the order data being sent by the Api.

**Suggested solution**

We need to filter the order data that WooCommerce is sending, and avoid sending the `line_items -> meta_data -> field` where the key is `_fpd_product_thumbnail`.

*(We can't delete the field, since its used internally for other cases.)*

Comment: Try `woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object` filter hook, You can see a basic example here to understand the param of this filter. https://sarathlal.com/customize-modify-woocommerce-rest-api-response-using-filter/
You'll have to remove the `_fpd_product_thumbnail` entry from the response then return the modified response from the filter.

Comment: Try `woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object` filter hook, You can see a basic example here to understand the param of this filter. https://sarathlal.com/customize-modify-woocommerce-rest-api-response-using-filter/
You'll have to remove the `_fpd_product_thumbnail` entry from the response then return the modified response from the filter.

Comment: Thank you very much, @VijayHardaha! I was able to put together a code based on that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example provided by @VijayHardaha I was able to put together a working code.

For anyone facing the same issue with Fancy Product Designer sending to large data to Zapier, you can use the following code to remove the image data from the REST API for Zapier only.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 'filter_order_response', 10, 3);
function filter_order_response($response, $post, $request){
  global $wpdb;
  $zapier_user_id = 1320; // User ID of the "Zapier" account in WordPress
  if(get_current_user_id() == $zapier_user_id) {

    $i = 0;
    $lineItemsCount = count($response->data["line_items"]);

    while($i < $lineItemsCount) {
      $j = 0;
      $metaDataCount = count($response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"]);
      
      while($j < $metaDataCount) {
        if($response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][$j]["key"] == "_fpd_product_thumbnail") {
          $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][$j]["value"] = "";
          $response->data["line_items"][$i]["meta_data"][$j]["display_value"] = "";
        }
        $j++;
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I have same problem and your solution is great. Thing is that sometimes I need those meta because we use thumbnails for item production. So is there some way how to add some parameter to request and get metas on demand?